# Changing transformation of already reprojected raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, landsat

I am pretty confused by projecting data from one coordinate system to another, especially if multiple transformation options are available (ArcGIS 10.4).

I downloaded Landsat LT5 data (origCS = GSC: WGS84, EPSG:4326) and I reprojected it to final PCS: S-JTSK (desiredCS = EPSG: 5514). Multiple transformations are available in ArcGIS:

[image]

I therefore applied the NGA transformation (S_JTSK_To_WGS_1984_NGA, called _nga) and further processed and classified my rasters.

Now,  I am thinking to change the way how Landsat has been projected, i.e change transformation #1 to transformation #2, keeping the original (WGS84) and final coordinate systems (S-JTSK) the same.

If that is possible and "legal", what is correct approach to do that?

As processing of my projected rasters has taken lot of time, I don't want to start again with the raw Landsat data, and I prefer to play around with transformation of classified rasters.

---

My thoughts how to change transformations of final rasters are:

1. simply transform the `raster_nga` to `raster_t2` (from one transformation to another, staying in S-JTSK) - is this possible?
2. project one landsat_wgs to lansat_t2 (by transformation 2) and use it as master scene  to resample final classified rasters?
3. something else??
4. is this needed or even not at all??

I am working on study area of size 400 km2, using single Lansat scene per time.

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question

Comment: The rasters that are now in S-JTSK are already there. If you want to reproject to WGS84 just use a different transformation. If you want to change how you got from WGS84 to S-JTSK you would have to reproject the rasters with the new transformation.